# How to know what Item of a MenuStrip is being clicked?

Tags: c#, menustrip

I'm using c# and I have a MenuStrip control but I don't know how to identify what item of it is being clicked. For example, I used to group all click(buttons) events in one or two methods like "btnActions_click()" or "btnNavigation_click()". Then, inside of the method I identify the button clicked by parsing the sender as a button and placing it on a button var, then I check if the name of that button var is equal to "btnFoo" or "btnBar".

So, in this case, how could I know what item of the MenuStrip controls is being clicked in order to group all click events in only one method?

I apologyze if my english isn't correct. If you can't understand me I can try again or post some code.

Thanks.

Edit: I didn't post any code because I thought that there was not necessary in this question but someone suggest me to do it, so I'll do it. Here's an example of what I do to identify what button has been clicked.

```
private void btnNavegation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        if (btn.Name == "btnNext")
             //go to next item of the list
        else if (btn.Name == "btnPrevious")
             //go to previous item of the list
    }
```

Comment: Post some code, always post code. Preferably something that runs easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to subscribe to [ItemClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.itemclicked(v=vs.110).aspx) event (inherited from `ToolStrip`), instead of subscribing to [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx) event (inherited from `Control`).

The example provided by Microsoft's documentation show you how to determine the clicked item on each call (`ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs::ClickedItem`):

```
private void ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(Object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "ClickedItem", e.ClickedItem );
    messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "ItemClicked Event" );
}
```